# How use DZ.player.getTrackList

Tags: javascript, deezer

I am trying to use Deezer Javascript SDK to get all track of playlist, but no sucess.

http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/player_object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can get the tracklist of a playlist after you loaded it through DZ.player.playPlaylist() (cf http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/loadtracks).

After that, you can use DZ.player.getTrackList() to retrieve the tracks in the queue.